# How can we access to inputs of ng-select for unit test?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-ngselect

My goal is to test if some  inputs like for example [isOpen] or [multiple] are equal to true.

I haven't any idea of how to access at this inputs, I tried by the DOM but it doesn't work.  Please help me .

```
<ng-select
        [ngModel]="carsInit"
        (change)="changeCars($event)"
        [items]="cars$ | async"
        [clearable]="false"
        [multiple]="true"
        [placeholder]="placeholderCars$ | async"
        [isOpen]="true"
      ></ng-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

While it may be valuable to test if ng-select works properly I think it should not be the scope of your test. If it were variables in your Component you could test those, but testing the functionality of ng-select is the scope of ng-select.